# Keras over tensorflow: Input to reshape is a tensor with 10830 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 11913

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, yolo, darknet

Firstly I'll give some context, prior to running into this issue i was using a pytorch yolov3+SORT implementation with custom weights and modified yolov3 architecture (https://github.com/cfotache/pytorch_objectdetecttrack).
The model and weights were created for darknet, but that implementation adapts it to pytorch and worked fine, the weights where handed to me and i had nothing to do with the training process.
So currently I'm trying to run a deepSORT+yolov3 repo (https://github.com/Qidian213/deep_sort_yolov3) for comparison in terms of accuracy. This implementation uses keras over tensorflow, and includes a script for creating .h5 from .cfg and .weights files
Firstly I ran the code with the default yolov3 architecture and the coco weights, and worked fined. But I can't get the code to work with the .h5 model created from the custom darknet model, the error points to the session.run() line (see code), I'm guessing it has to do with the input tensor shape, I've checked the input image resolution (608x608x3) like a dozen times both in the code and in the .cfg file, i don't know what else to do to get the model to work, the architecture is proven both in pytorch and darknet, and shouldn't be the problem.

(code for the detections)

```
def detect_image(self, image):
    if self.is_fixed_size:
        assert self.model_image_size[0]%32 == 0, 'Multiples of 32 required'
        assert self.model_image_size[1]%32 == 0, 'Multiples of 32 required'
        boxed_image = letterbox_image(image, tuple(reversed(self.model_image_size)))
    else:
        new_image_size = (image.width - (image.width % 32),
                          image.height - (image.height % 32))
        boxed_image = letterbox_image(image, new_image_size)
    image_data = np.array(boxed_image, dtype='float32')

    #print(image_data.shape)
    image_data /= 255.
    image_data = np.expand_dims(image_data, 0)  # Add batch dimension.

    out_boxes, out_scores, out_classes = self.sess.run(
        [self.boxes, self.scores, self.classes],
        feed_dict={
            self.yolo_model.input: image_data,
            self.input_image_shape: [image.size[1], image.size[0]],
            K.learning_phase(): 0
        })
```

Thanks in advance.